# Easier way to toggle field descriptions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I've got a simple form that takes user feedback.  Basically I just want to toggle the input values - Name, E-mail, Subject, Comments.

```
<form name="email_rep" id="email_rep" method="POST">
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust" value="Name" maxlength="100" class="fields" onFocus="toggleLabels(1)" onBlur="toggleLabels(5)">
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust_email" maxlength="100" value="E-mail" class="fields" onFocus="toggleLabels(2)" onBlur="toggleLabels(6)"><br />
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust_subject" value="Subject" maxlength="100" class="fields-alt" onFocus="toggleLabels(3)" onBlur="toggleLabels(7)"><br />
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust_comment" maxlength="500" value="Comments" class="fields-alt" onFocus="toggleLabels(4)" onBlur="toggleLabels(8)"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit_email" id="submit" onClick="sendButton()">
</form>
```

and the corresponding JS:

```
function toggleLabels(x) {
    switch(x) {
        case 1: (document.email_rep.cust.value=="Name") ? (document.email_rep.cust.value="") : (false); break;
        case 2: (document.email_rep.cust_email.value=="E-mail") ? (document.email_rep.cust_email.value="") : (false); break;
        case 3: (document.email_rep.cust_subject.value=="Subject") ? (document.email_rep.cust_subject.value="") : (false); break;
        case 4: (document.email_rep.cust_comment.value=="Comments") ? (document.email_rep.cust_comment.value="") : (false); break;
        case 5: (document.email_rep.cust.value=="") ? (document.email_rep.cust.value="Name") : (false); break;
        case 6: (document.email_rep.cust_email.value=="") ? (document.email_rep.cust_email.value="E-mail") : (false); break;
        case 7: (document.email_rep.cust_subject.value=="") ? (document.email_rep.cust_subject.value="Subject") : (false); break;
        case 8: (document.email_rep.cust_comment.value=="") ? (document.email_rep.cust_comment.value="Comments") : (false); break;
    }
}
```

I mean it works, but it's not exactly concise and definitely isn't reusable.  I was thinking passing another variable - say "y" where y="email_rep", and possibly another - say "z" where z="Name"/"E-mail"/"Subject"/"Comments", but it's not working for me, I don't know if it's like the strings being passed or what the issue is.  Any suggestions for making this simpler?

Comment: easiest is using jquery instead of js http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: How would I be able to apply toggle() to toggle the form field values?

Comment: HTML5 supports the "placeholder" attribute on text inputs. Not a universal solution, but certainly concise.

Comment: @zod: I think you meant to say "instead of **native** js" ;)

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy It wouldn't; zod's comment won't work.

Comment: Forgot about that... Do you know if the HTML5shiv will cover me if it's not supported?

Comment: It will only work in the more recent browsers. Think IE9+ (might be wrong), any recent version of Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
function toggleLabelValue(obj, val) {
    if (obj.value == val) {
        obj.value = "";
    } else {
        obj.value = val;
    }
}

// examples:
toggleLabelValue(document.email_rep.cust, "Name");
toggleLabelValue(document.email_rep.cust_email, "E-mail");
```

Or, since all your objects have the same root, you could build that root into the function like this:

```
function toggleRepLabelValue(field, val) {
    if (document.email_rep[field].value == val) {
        document.email_rep[field].value = "";
    } else {
        document.email_rep[field].value = val;
    }
}

// examples:
toggleRepLabelValue("cust", "Name");
toggleRepLabelValue("cust_email", "E-mail");
```

Comment: That looks precisely like what I need, I'll test it and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work. It uses placeholders, but also uses jQuery to simulate placeholder functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/kmkRV/

```
$(function() {
    $("input:text").each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
    }).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
        }
    });
});
```

That's the jQuery javascript. Here's the HTML:

```
<form name="email_rep" id="email_rep" method="POST">    
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust" placeholder="Name" maxlength="100">    
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust_email" maxlength="100" placeholder="E-mail"><br />     
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust_subject" placeholder="Subject"><br />     
    <input type="text" width="100" name="cust_comment" maxlength="500" placeholder="Comments"><br />     
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit_email" id="submit" onClick="sendButton()"> </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has a lovely new attribute for input fields called `placeholder`.

Although this isn't supported by some browsers yet, I thought it worth pointing out as an answer for future readers.

You basically use it like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP9z3/

In Firefox, placing focus on the input removed the placeholder text, and on blur, if a new value isn't entered, the placeholder text is restored.

**UPDATE**

Using jQuery you can also mimick the behaviour of the placeholder with a small bit of code:

```
$('input:text').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
    }
}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP9z3/3/

This basically sets up each input so that it's placeholder text is used if it is empty.

Comment: Does the HTML5shiv degrade this if it's not supported?

Comment: if it's "not supported" it simply acts as any normal input would.

Comment: True, but then that would kind of defeat the purpose of using it in the first place, because I would then have to account for form labels, or fall back on the script I already have in place.

Comment: Like I said, I've included this answer because it may be of use to others in the future.

Comment: See my update also. This works for all input elements on the page so no need to keep adding new ones each time.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, I've come up with possibly the most re-usable solution. Yes, it uses jQuery, however it's a very powerful, useful tool.

I've done some magic with `.data()` to store the original value. Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/pyS6V/).

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
        $(this).data("placeholder", $(this).val());
    });

    $("input").live("focus", function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data("placeholder"))
        {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $("input").live("blur", function() {
        if(!$(this).val().length)
        {
            $(this).val($(this).data("placeholder"));
        }
    });
});
```

You could probably shrink it by a few lines, but I wanted it to be clear. Also, this will affect any new elements added dynamically to the DOM, due to using `.live()`.

---

**EDIT**

To make for cleaner markup, have a look at [THIS JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/pyS6V/5/); it grabs the `placeholder` attribute and puts it into `value` as a fallback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
        $(this).data("placeholder", $(this).attr("placeholder"));
        $(this).val($(this).data("placeholder"));
    });

    $("input").live("focus", function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data("placeholder"))
        {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $("input").live("blur", function() {
        if(!$(this).val().length)
        {
            $(this).val($(this).data("placeholder"));
        }
    });
}    );
```

Comment: Hmm..this seems to work even if I don't use the placeholder attr...does that matter?

Comment: Not at all. Personally, I'd use the `placeholder` attribute for browsers that support it, but use this jQuery as a fallback. Also, please see my edits.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a need to loop through each input like this. See the update to my answer for cut down solution.

Comment: @Jamie Nice one. My example obviously has the same functionality, however I wanted to make it a bit more verbose, as well as use `.live()` to make it dynamic-friendly.